# Nautilus search-as-you-type layout (language) independent

Tags: nautilus, keyboard-layout, language-support, search

It is very handy to have a search-as-you-type be automatically adopted to any keyboard layout available on the computer. So you do not have to switch between the languages when you are surfing your disks.

For example, if you have the following files in the directory:

- first
- second
- раз
- два

To find "first" you can type "first" or "ашкые" (which will be "first" with standard Russian layout turned on). And vice versa to find "раз" you can type "hfp".

This search behaviour you can find in Telegram application.

Is there any way to realise such behaviour in the Nautilus search?